# AVFoundation video recording does not return camera intrinsics if recording at 240fps

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation, camera-calibration

I'm using the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` delegate method to capture video buffers and then write out to file using an `AVAssetWriter`. When configuring the recording session I'm checking for camera intrinsics delivery support and enabling this to pick up the intrinsics from the buffer:

```
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        if (self.connection.isCameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliverySupported) {
            self.connection.cameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliveryEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
```

In `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` I am then obtaining intrinsics using:

```
CFTypeRef cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil);
```

All works fine and I can extract the intrinsics values I want - when recording at 60fps or 120fps.

When the camera format is changed to set an appropriate 720p (detected and saved previously during initial device detection and configuration - and I tried 420f or 420v formats - makes no difference) format and the framerate set at 240 fps, no intrinsics are available - or, rather, very low and effectively zero values are passed through in the intrinsics matrix.

Checking the value of `self.connection.isCameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliverySupported` in `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` returns `YES` at 60 fps or 120 fps, but `NO` at 240 fps. It simply appears not to be returned any more at the higher framerate.

Does anybody have any idea why this is - or have any recommendations for consistently retrieving intrinsics at all framerates?

Thanks in advance for any help!